# Bash function only write one word in file from a string

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script to clean log files on a system at work.
There for i have created a logging for maintenance.
Only the logging writes one word instead of the sentence.

Here the bash code I used.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    FILEDIR=/<file>/<directory>
    COPYDIR=/</
    LOGDIR=/mnt/orabackup/??IPLUS/pmt/log/
    INFO="[INF] :" 
    INFO1="There are no files found for cleanup."
    INFO2="There are files found for cleanup."

    ERROR="[ERR] :"
    ERROR1="there was a error while running the script." 
    ERROR2="(Error while cleanup files whitout pid)"
    ERROR3="(Error while cleanup large files whit pid)"
    function writelog
    {
        string=$1
        echo $(date +%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S) ": ${string}"  >> ${LOGDIR}script.log
    }

    for NOPID in $(ls -1 ${FILEDIR}*.trc|awk -F "_" '{print $3}'|awk -F "." '{print $1}' |uniq)
      do 
        ps -ef|grep oracle|grep -v grep|grep -v LOCAL|grep -v "su -"|grep $NOPID > /dev/null
      if [ $? = 1 ]
      then 
        ls -1sh ${FILEDIR} | grep $NOPID > ${LOGDIR}${TIMESTAMP}deleted_logs_whitout_pid.log
        rm -f ${FILEDIR}*$NOPID.tr?
      elif [ $? = 0 ]
      then 
        writelog ${INFO}${INFO1}
      else 
        writelog ${ERROR}${ERROR1}${ERROR2}
      fi
    done
```

When I execute the script and I look in the created log file from the writelog function, it logs only the date stamp and the first word like:

```
20151224T08:15:28 : [INF]
```

Instead of the whole sentence like:

```
 20151224T08:15:28 : [INF] :There are no files found for cleanup.
```

I have no clou what I'm doing wrong. If I echo the statement it works.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: `writelog` only writes `$1` to the file. That's just the first argument to the function.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writelog` only writes its first argument to the log. You need to quote the variables when you call it so that they'll all be in a single argument, instead of being split into separate words.

```
 then 
    writelog "${INFO}${INFO1}"
  else 
    writelog "${ERROR}${ERROR1}${ERROR2}"
  fi
```

Get in the habit of **always** quoting your variables. It's very rare that you need to perform word splitting or wildcard expansion on the result of a variable expansion. When you do, you should know it.

Comment: Thank you Barmar you're answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' file.log
```